# SQL - From [spoiler:abcdefgh] to [spoiler]

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I've this string in many records `[spoiler:abcdefgh]`. `abcdefgh` are variable characters. I want this to became `[spoiler]`. So I want to remove `:abcdefgh`.

I know that the query is:

```
UPDATE post 
SET pagetext = replace(pagetext, ‘text you want to replace’, ‘replacament text’);
```

How can I replace variable characters?

For example, if I have `[center:uezfbb79]texttt[/center:uezfbb79]` then I want this to became: `[center]texttt[/center]`

"uezfbb79" are not fixed, these are random characters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: I'm not expert of mysql, so if possible i need someone that tell me "do this." It's an urgent think, it's the first time I'm using MYSQL, I don't know what to do.. :(

Comment: @flup - Since MySql does not provide simple `REGEXP_REPLACE` functionality, it seems that each case might need to be treated differently.

Comment: maybe I can use any php script?

Comment: If PHP supports replacement using *regular exceptions*, it may be a safer approach.  Please see my SQL code posted below.

Comment: @PM77-1 In MYSQL, UDFs are the way to go if you need the full power of regular expressions inside the database, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the trick, assuming that all your tags are properly formatted.  Please test **throroughly** before running against the production copy.

```
UPDATE post
SET pagetext = REPLACE(pagetext, SUBSTR(pagetext, INSTR(pagetext,':'), INSTR(pagetext, ']') - INSTR(pagetext,':')), '')
WHERE pagetext LIKE '[%:%]';
```

Here's **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1c71/2)** I used for **very** limited testing.

**EDIT**

This script should properly deal with preceding `[]` situation:

```
UPDATE post
SET pagetext = REPLACE(pagetext, SUBSTR(pagetext, @c1:=INSTR(pagetext,':'), LOCATE(']', pagetext, @c1) - @c1), '')
WHERE pagetext LIKE '[%:%]';
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93d632/1)**

**EDIT #2**

My `WHERE` clause was too restrictive.  Here's a slightly updated script:

```
UPDATE post
SET pagetext = REPLACE(pagetext, SUBSTR(pagetext, @c1:=INSTR(pagetext,':'), LOCATE(']', pagetext, @c1) - @c1), '')
WHERE pagetext LIKE '%[%:%]%';
```

I changed the **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c7eb2/2)** to update another column (`newtext`), so it's easier to judge the results.

Comment: In the records I've also some test like: "here's an example: if this works...". I think that your query will change also these records. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I've tried, and it changed "example:text" to "example]text" :(

Comment: My query will look only at the fields that have opening and closing square brackets a with colon between them (`[... :...]`) (see `WHERE` clause) and then it will remove everything between `:` (inclusive) and `]` (exclusive).

Comment: You can go inside the `Fiddle` (link in my post) and play with the data.

Comment: My script, for example, should change `[:]example]` to `]]`.  You may want to post some extreme samples of your real data to look at.

Comment: I've tried to do this again, but nothing to do. Maybe it crashes when it meets numbers? Oh, and thank you so much for the help!

Comment: For example, this code has been converted: [center:uezfbb79]. This one hasn't been converted: [center:cdaz445u] . :/

Comment: THIS HASN'T BEEN EDITED: [size=7][color=#FF0000][center:2k7zks67]Procedura per trasferire i File Opzioni all&#39;interno della PS3[/center:2k7zks67][/color][/size]
[quote]text[/quote]. THIS HAS BEEN EDITED: [center:34jst32f][color=#FF0000][size=7]Procedura per trasferire un File mp3 all&#39;interno della PS3 (Cori, Musiche)[/size][/color][/center:34jst32f]
[quote]text[/quote]

Comment: And what happens with URL? They're bulit in this way: [URL=http://url]url[/URL] :(

Comment: You can enhance `WHERE` clause to exclude anything that has `URL` in it.

Comment: Ok, thank you again, but I still have this problem. I've tried also with SQL Fiddle and it's a problem. Do you know what could I do? THIS HASN'T BEEN EDITED: [size=7][color=#FF0000][center:2k7zks67]Procedura per trasferire i File Opzioni all&#39;interno della PS3[/center:2k7zks67][/color][/size] [quote]text[/quote]. THIS HAS BEEN EDITED: [center:34jst32f][color=#FF0000][size=7]Procedura per trasferire un File mp3 all&#39;interno della PS3 (Cori, Musiche)[/size][/color][/center:34jst32f] [quote]text[/quote]

Comment: I understood that the problem is because of [] before [center: in the row, but I don't know how to solve the problem. :(

Comment: I'm trying to focus only on the 'center' tag. Maybe it's easier in this way to solve the problem. Please let me know. THANK YOU FOR EVERYTHING!

Comment: It doesn't work. It has changed also something that shouldn't be changed like [color=#555] tag :(

Comment: I do not see the sample with `[color=#555]`. Is it well formed? Please post it. I believe the script worked for the samples you provided so far. Or have I missed something?

Comment: Well, there're hundred of topics. It was an example: after I imported the script color tags were wrong. I had start the your script many times, and EVERY times i started it, it edited something, so it means that something went wrong I think. And also, and most important, this HASN'T BEEN EDITED: [center:2a5rsgtu][img]http://img213.imageshack.us/img213/4826/masselsonxg8.png [/img][/center:2a5rsgtu]ol e Nelson possono ufficialmente rilasciare il loro File Opzioni per PS3!

Comment: Also this is not edited with the scirpt: [center:2a5rsgtu][img]h. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Maybe we can work with the fact that the character after between : and ] are always 8 character?

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem, but still have no idea what causes it.  It becomes interesting.

Comment: Solved it. The problem was in a `WHERE` clause: it was working only on strings that start with `[` and end with `]`.  Will post the update shortly.

Comment: THANK YOU, you're my legend! Now I've a problem with charset :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634577/mysql-from-utf8-bin-to-latin1-swedish-ci